# Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm using `meteor.js` and I just went to change some of the HTML output in the .html file only and it started giving me the error:

> Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'

I haven't changed anything, the only thing I recall doing inbetween is starting a new project which I created using meteor.js, which then updated meteor and now I have this problem.

Rest of error details:

> Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.049(1)? (STDERR)     at validateDatabaseName (/Users/jumpingcode/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:216:59)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.050(1)? (STDERR)     at new Db (/Users/jumpingcode/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:90:3)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.050(1)? (STDERR)     at MongoClient.connect.connectFunction (/Users/jumpingcode/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:238:29)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.050(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/jumpingcode/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:291:5)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.050(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.Db.connect (/Users/jumpingcode/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/86ae77f282/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1854:23)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.051(1)? (STDERR)     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:113)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.051(1)? (STDERR)     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:3)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.051(1)? (STDERR)     at Object. (packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:34)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.051(1)? (STDERR)     at Object._.once [as defaultRemoteCollectionDriver] (packages/underscore/underscore.js:704)
>
> W20130828-09:52:22.053(1)? (STDERR)     at new Meteor.Collection (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your collection in `.meteor/local/db` to see if any files were added in.

If it really still continues you could use `meteor reset` but it would clear your database.

The issue arises from mongodb, because `.` notation lets you peak inside objects in javascript the character is reserved and can't be used as a collection or database name.

If there is any environmental variable that you've used it could also cause the issue with a new typo or something. Try using just `meteor` like you usually would in a fresh terminal window.

Comment: Seems to have worked, there's a whole host of other issues but this seems to have fixed the db thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when I use expressjs with mongoose, above error was occured.It resolve by doing

1.create a database.js file

make a exportble database configuration inside it as follows

```
module.exports = {database : "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@ds161039.mlab.com:61039/accounttest"};
```

2.Require it to your current JS file

```
var connection = mongoose.connect(config.database);
```